# Can the BST file for BIBTEX be composed of several files?

Tags: macros, bibtex, bst

References in various journals are required to be presented in different formats. But journal abbreviations are often identical. Is it possible to prepare a single file of macros with journal abbreviations to be inserted in various BST files for BIBTEX?

Comment: JabRef can change automatically long and abbreviated journal names of your whole database o a singel reference according to a preinstalled list of journals, or your custom list. Left macros and .bst files for another taks.

Answer (score 1):

No, the `bst` syntax does not provide a function to load files other than `.bib`. You may consider storing the abbreviation definitions (`@string`) in a `.bib` file.